# Why are the link/span tags in my <marquee> appearing on several lines in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, marquee

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="10" onmouseover="style.cursor='hand';   this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);"                       onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 6, 0);" id="ticker" direction="right">
   <div style="width:719px ;height:20px; font-family:Arial;color:red"id="ticker01">
       <span>1/2/2011</span><a href="a.aspx">one</a>
       <span>2/2/2011</span><a href="b.aspx">two</a>
       <span>3/2/2011</span><a href="c.aspx">three</a>
       <span>4/2/2011</span><a href="d.aspx">four</a>           
   </div>
</marquee>
```

In IE8:GOOOOOOOD!!!!

shown:1/2/2011 one  2/2/2011 two 3/2/2011 three 4/2/2011 four

only in one line.

BUT

In Firefox:Problem????????

shown:

```
       1/2/2011 one 
       2/2/2011 two
       3/2/2011 three
       4/2/2011 four
```

All together, several lines are moving

jquery, the equivalent of someone to do the same and is from right to left are;;

Comment: The marquee tag is deprecated by the W3C. I would suggest looking for a jquery alternative instead.

Comment: jquery marquee? : http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html

Comment: Ugh, the native one is *so* much better-looking. jQuery makes it chunky...

Comment: Ironically the native one was deprecated largely because most end-users found it ugly and annoying. It was heavily abused by crap homepages on Geocities. I won't miss it.

Comment: Seems logical to me that this would happen, you put them all in one div. Remove the div tag. I think the fact that this works in IE is just a testament to how not standard complient IE is.

Comment: @Elad: I don't think you can complain about IE, it tried something new, it wasn't liked, it got deprecated. That's how web stadnards are developing now (innerHTML, xmlHttpRequest, Canvas, etc.).

Comment: @RobG: not talking about the marquee, talking about displaying one-by-one elements that are placed in the same div. I use IE9 now and develop in asp.net, so I'm not a Microsoft hater :)

Comment: @Elad: sure, but despite being in one `<div>`, all the elements he’s using are inline, so they *should* all display on the same line in all browsers. If each link/span combination was in its own `<div>`, *then* you’d expect the layout he’s seeing.

Comment: @Paul - Good point. Maybe there is some style floating them left? @ashkufaraz - Try looking at the styles applied through firebug.

Comment: What you've posted works just fine for me in the latest Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/f8fCF/. What's going on in your stylesheets?

Comment: Stack Overflow really should acquire JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Firefox might be rendering the line breaks within the `<marquee>` tag as if they were `<br>` tags?

Bit annoying, but could you try removing the line breaks?

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="10" onmouseover="style.cursor='hand';   this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);"                       onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 6, 0);" id="ticker" direction="right">
   <div style="width:719px ;height:20px; font-family:Arial;color:red"id="ticker01">
       <span>1/2/2011</span><a href="a.aspx">one</a> <span>2/2/2011</span><a href="b.aspx">two</a> <span>3/2/2011</span><a href="c.aspx">three</a> <span>4/2/2011</span><a href="d.aspx">four</a>           
   </div>
</marquee>
```